# How can I style the "wp_nav_menu" link for the current page?

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have looked around and I can't seem to find a straightforward way to do this.  I have a list of pages for my dropdown menu using wp_nav_menu and I just want to make the link to the page you are currently on be a different color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the selector `current-menu-item`? This should work :)

Comment: Yepppp that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a condition on base of it wordpress consider it as an active menu. 
So you have to make css class for different color you can see the class of current active like 'page_item page-item-36 current_page_item' for that nothing more. So make a class with attributes you wold like .

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the end of your webfish stylesheet

```
  #DropDownMenuNav ul.children,
    #DropDownMenuNav ul.DropDownMenu li.current_page_item
    {
    background: #D0251E; // Any color code you want
    }
```